# Python Thread Synchronizing

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization

I want to ask about the difference of the below 2 codes. In both, I have use queueLock.acquire(), but why the first code run Thread-2 after Thread-1 have finished, in the second code the Threads run in random, not waiting the previous one to finish?

**First code:**

```
class myThread (threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.threadID = threadID
      self.name = name
      self.counter = counter
   def run(self):
      print "Starting " + self.name
      threadLock.acquire()
      print_time(self.name, self.counter, 2)
      threadLock.release()

def print_time(threadName, delay, counter):
   while counter:
      time.sleep(delay)
      print "%s: %s" % (threadName, time.ctime(time.time()))
      counter -= 1

threadLock = threading.Lock()

# Create new threads
thread1 = myThread(1, "Thread-1", 1)
thread2 = myThread(2, "Thread-2", 2)

# Start new Threads
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

**The result is**

Starting Thread-1

Starting Thread-2

Thread-1: Thu Oct 15 08:06:09 2020

Thread-1: Thu Oct 15 08:06:10 2020

Thread-2: Thu Oct 15 08:06:13 2020

Thread-2: Thu Oct 15 08:06:17 2020

**Second code:**

```
exitFlag = 0

class myThread (threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, threadID, name, q):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.threadID = threadID
      self.name = name
      self.q = q
   def run(self):
      print "Starting " + self.name
      process_data(self.name, self.q)
      print "Exiting " + self.name

def process_data(threadName, q):
   while not exitFlag:
      queueLock.acquire()
      if not workQueue.empty():
            data = q.get()
            queueLock.release()
            print "%s processing %s" % (threadName, data)
      else:
            queueLock.release()
            time.sleep(1)

threadList = ["Thread-1", "Thread-2", "Thread-3"]
nameList = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]
queueLock = threading.Lock()
workQueue = Queue.Queue(10)
threads = []
threadID = 1

# Create new threads
for tName in threadList:
   thread = myThread(threadID, tName, workQueue)
   thread.start()
   threads.append(thread)
   threadID += 1

# Fill the queue
queueLock.acquire()
for word in nameList:
   workQueue.put(word)
queueLock.release()

# Wait for queue to empty
while not workQueue.empty():
   pass

# Notify threads it's time to exit
exitFlag = 1

# Wait for all threads to complete
for t in threads:
   t.join()
print "Exiting Main Thread"
```

**The result is**

Starting Thread-1

Starting Thread-2

Starting Thread-3

Thread-1 processing One

Thread-3 processing Two

Thread-2 processing Three

Thread-1 processing Four

Thread-3 processing Five

Exiting Thread-3

Exiting Thread-2

Exiting Thread-1

Exiting Main Thread

Answer (score 1):

In the first code both threads lock, do their work, then unlock. The first thread is started slightly earlier than the second, so it is the one who locks first. The second one can proceed past its lock only after the first unlocks, that is why the order is always the same.

In the second code when a thread finds that the `workQueue` is empty, then it releases the lock, sleeps, and tries again. This gives an opportunity for other threads to lock and check whether there is anything in the queue.
By the time the queue is filled up, most probably all of the threads are in their sleep, and there is some [uncertainty](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/time.html#time.sleep) about the order they wake up. This causes the "randomness" in the order they process queue elements.

It is not clear what you mean by "not waiting the previous one to finish", because they wait for each other to finish with respect to getting elements from the queue.

Also, it must be noted that your programs use an interesting mix of techniques for thread coordination: locks, synchronised queue, sleep, busy waiting, and a global variable. This is not against the law, but more diverse than it should be.